# Signing App for Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Okay first of all I am not entirely sure how I tell Android Studio to build for me in Debug mode but what I have done is running the *Gradle task* `assembleDebug` after creating the key.

What I have done is

1. going to `Build > Generate Signed APK...` and created my key.
2. Find `app-debug.apk` and `app-release.apk` in the directory  `mahlzeit\app`
3. Run `assembleDebug` Gradle task
4. Run App

But I keep getting this error:

```
04-19 18:42:15.465  29617-29734/com.mahlzeit E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
04-19 18:42:15.565  29617-29734/com.mahlzeit E/Google Maps Android API﹕ In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
API Key: AIzaSyC0qtZwwJ7CpOgZEYFyu1Ex_7BqsG5MUj0
Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 
    ...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you have 2 API key you have used in project. Try to place it in "YOUR_KEY_HERE" to avoid overwrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Maps API key you generated is probably only for the Debug build. If you plan on releasing the app signed, then you will need to add the SHA-1 fingerprint for your certificate to your google account.

As suggested in the error log enter your debug and signed SHA-1 fingerprint for your certificate in the [Google API console](https://console.developers.google.com/project).

Also you can select the correct build to run with:

1. Select the build variants tab from bottom left of Android Studio
2. Select the variant for the module using the drop down where it currently display "debug"

[image: Build variants]

3. Press run

[image: Run]

Comment: I don't understand. If I run my App after `assembleDebug` everything should be built in debug mode or am I wrong here? I don't care about release mode at the moment. And to be honest I have no idea what I have to do at the Google API console O_O

Comment: I assume you followed the instructions here?: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key

Comment: Well... I saw that there was a SHA1-key under the field `Android applications`. I removed that, created a new one without that key, got my new API key and now it is working. This SHA1-key is supposed to restrict access to my API key right? Such that only *my* Apps may use this API key right?

Comment: Exactly that, the combination of signing fingerprint and package name are used by Google's servers to ensure that your API key is only used by your app.

Comment: plus one for the build variants! Thank you

Comment: Okay I see! So right now anyone could use my API key. I better work that out :D